# How to create a model with MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

So far I had understand that model in MVC is to construct data structure, such as store/access data from database. But then I got loss on how to construct a success structure.

Within a database, there are say, 5 tables. Shall I first making a namespace that consisted all tables into DbConText and followed by construct all tables into Dbset?

Is there any article that help for linking a built DB, and demostrate the steps on how to do?

Comment: Do you wana make a custom MVC structure?

Comment: What do you mean by Custom, does creating a data set means custom? If so yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Mvc it is very simple for create a model. You just follow the following steps..

http://nerddinnerbook.s3.amazonaws.com/Part3.htm

Comment: Many thanks, looks like I cant learn more from the NerdDinner example